# Why using a constexpr instead of define?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I wanted to created a `define` function like that:

```
#define TEST0(x)   ((x==0)?0.00000001:x)
```

But Visual recommend me to use a `constexpr` like that:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto TEST0(T x) { return ((x==0)?0.00000001:x); }
```

What's the advantage?

Comment: macros are the devil 

Comment: Consider for example `TEST0(x++)`.